# Can not push commits on local git server

Tags: git

i have a repository on my local computer in which there are several files i want to push to my local git server whose ip address is 192.168.10.8 and the user under which all git repositories exist is "git".

on git server i have created a directory and set it up as a git repository by following commands:

```
mkdir top-reports.git
cd top-reports.git
git init --bare
```

on my local computer i've added remote origin as follows:

```
git remote add origin git@192.168.10.8:git/top-reports.git
```

and then:

```
git push -u origin master
```

after entering the password for the user "git" i receive this error:

```
fatal: 'git/top-report.git' does not appear to be a
git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i have followed lots of discussions regarding the same error message but non have fixed my issue.

Comment: So inside the home directory of the user `git`, you have a subdirectory also called `git` that contains the directory `top-reports.git`. So the full path is something like `/home/git/git/top-reports.git`?

Comment: @RichardSmith no, in the home directory of the user `git` there is only a subdirectory named `top-reports.git`. the reason i add the url as `git@192.168.10.8:git/top-reports.git` is that, in the discussions regarding the same issue i noticed after semicolon one should indicate the user. but i have also tried without it as well like `git@192.168.10.8:top-reports.git` but yet the same error message.

Comment: That URL is shorthand for the SSH protocol. The part after the `:` is the path relative to the user's home directory. I tested your process and the format like `git@192.168.10.8:top-reports.git` was the one that worked for me.

Comment: @RichardSmith might be any ssh configuration that i am missing ? because the error refers to "access rights" as well. also i should note that the `top-report.git` has `chmod` equal to 755

Comment: You have `top-reports.git` in your `mkdir`—reports, plural—but `top-report.git` (singular) in your error message. That's probably the entire problem.